# After using prefetch_related still facing n+1

Tags: django, django-models

I am facing multiple duplicate db call even after I am using prefetch_related.
Here is my views:

```
def index(request):
    product_qs = Product.objects.filter(shop_type='Grocery', featured=True, hide=False)
        product_list = product_qs.prefetch_related('image', 'size_list').order_by('ranking')
        products = terminator(request, product_list, 25)   // reusable paginator!
    context = {'categories': categories, 'products': products}
    return render(request, 'grocery/index.html', context)
```

Here is my models:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='shop/product')
    color = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image_thumbnail_index = ImageSpecField(source='image',
                                           processors=[ResizeToFill(308, 412)],
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           options={'quality': 100})
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    shop_type = models.CharField(choices=shop_options, max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    image = models.ManyToManyField(ProductImage)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    size = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    size_list = models.ManyToManyField(SizeList)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # out of stock ?
    hide = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # archive a product
    ranking = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

and the template:

```
<figure class="product-image-container">
    <a href="#" class="product-image">
        <img src="{{ product.image.first.image_thumbnail_index.url }}" alt="{{ products.name }}">
    </a>
    <a href="{% url 'grocery_quickview' %}?product={{ product.name }}" class="btn-quickview">{% trans 'Quickview' %}</a>
</figure>
<div class="product-details">
    <h2 class="product-title">
        <a href="/grocery/product/{{ product.slug }}">
            {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %}
                {{ product.name }}
            {% else %}
                {{ product.name_bn }}
            {% endif %}
        </a>
    </h2>
    <div class="price-box">
        <span class="product-price">
            {% if LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %}
                ৳ {{ product.price }}
            {% else %}
                ৳ {{ product.price_bn }}
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div><!-- End .price-box -->
```

Screenshot of sql calls:
[image]

Comment: how many "duplicated calls" do u have? cuz prefetch_related by its own makes 1 additional db call.

Comment: The fact that you query with `product.image.first` (the `.first()` is key here), "nullifies" the `prefetch_related`, since `prefetch_related` fetches the "entire" relation, and that is seen as "not relevant" when fetching the first one.

Comment: @Chiefir updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you are right, so right now what should I do if I want to avoid extra db call per object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already prefetching the `ProductImage` objects you may use the of the prefetched objects: `{% with product.image.all|first as image %}{{ image.image_thumbnail_index.url }}(% endwith %}`. (While calling `first()` does an extra query using `LIMIT 1` at the end.)

Comment: Image doesn't shows if I use  {{ product.image.0.image_thumbnail_index.url }}

Comment: thanks, I have to use `{% with product.image.all|first as image %}` without `.all` it throws `ManyRelatedManager object is not iterable`

Comment: yes you are right, i've also edited the answer accordingly!